# Group rows if they have overlapping time intervals

Tags: mysql

I need an SQL query to create a new field `group_id` which identifies records within each `ID` that have overlapping `start_time` and `end_time` intervals. An acceptable solution will have a unique `group_id` for each `ID` and overlapping set of intervals.
    Example:
    sample `times` table with group_id computed

```html
ID START_TIME END_TIME GROUP_ID
100 10:00:00 12:00:00 1
100 10:15:00 12:30:00 1
100 12:15:00 12:45:00 1
100 13:00:00 14:00:00 2
101 09:00:00 13:00:00 1
101 09:30:00 13:30:00 1
101 10:00:00 10:20:00 1
101 10:19:59 11:15:00 1
101 10:21:00 10:30:00 1
101 11:00:00 12:30:00 1
101 11:30:00 12:35:00 1
102 10:01:00 11:25:00 1
102 11:01:00 11:30:00 1
105 10:00:00 10:20:00 1
105 10:21:00 10:30:00 2
105 10:30:01 11:00:00 3
106 10:00:00 10:22:00 1
107 10:19:57 10:20:01 1
108 10:01:01 10:16:59 1
```

Additional Info: For a given `ID`, if any of its intervals overlap then the corresponding records belong to the same group, and thus should have the same `group_id`. A record A overlaps another record B when A’s `start_time` and/or `end_time` is between B’s `start_time` and `end_time`.

In the example, `ID` = 100 has four intervals. The first three overlap => the second record overlaps with the first (the `start_time` of 10:15 is between the `start_time` and `end_time` of 10:00 to 12:00) and the third overlaps with the second (the `start_time` of 12:15 is between the `start_time` and `end_time` of 10:15 to 12:30). Because of this, they all have the same `group_id` of 1. The fourth interval for `ID` = 100 does not overlap any of the other intervals within that `ID`, and so it becomes its own group with a new `group_id`. The last record has a completely different `ID` and so it starts a third group also with a new `group_id`.

edit: I've tried this MYSQL script. The output does not reset the group ID and continues in the serial order. Would like to know what changes can make it work.

```html
  
WITH C1 AS (
SELECT *,
  CASE 
WHEN start_time <= MAX(IFnull(end_time,'9999-12-31 00:00:00.000')) OVER(
  partition by id
  ORDER BY start_time 
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) 
  THEN 0 
  ELSE 1 
END AS isstart
FROM activity
) 
SELECT ID,start_time,end_time,
   SUM(isstart) OVER(ORDER BY ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS DG 
FROM C1;

Query Output:
100 10:00:00 12:00:00 1
100 10:15:00 12:30:00 1
100 12:15:00 12:45:00 1
100 13:00:00 14:00:00 2
101 09:00:00 13:00:00 3
101 09:30:00 13:30:00 3
101 10:00:00 10:20:00 3
101 10:19:59 11:15:00 3
101 10:21:00 10:30:00 3
101 11:00:00 12:30:00 3
101 11:30:00 12:35:00 3
102 10:01:00 11:25:00 4
102 11:01:00 11:30:00 4
105 10:00:00 10:20:00 5
105 10:21:00 10:30:00 6
105 10:30:01 11:00:00 7
106 10:00:00 10:22:00 8
107 10:19:57 10:20:01 9
108 10:01:01 10:16:59 10
```

(Removing the mysql-server tag)

Comment: First of all, have you tried any query yet? If you have, please post the query into your question and tell us what version of MySQL you're using? If you haven't, you should try something first then update your question if you're facing any issue.

Comment: what's the primary key?

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server? Those are quite different db engines.

Comment: You need MySQL 8.x or SQL Server 2012 (or newer). Please specify engine and version.

Comment: I've added the code that I was trying in the question.

Comment: @Nav did you just post an interview question online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH C1 AS (
SELECT *,
  CASE 
WHEN start_time <= MAX(IFnull(end_time,'9999-12-31 00:00:00.000')) OVER(
  partition by id
  ORDER BY start_time 
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) 
  THEN 0 
  ELSE 1 
END AS isstart
FROM activity
) 
SELECT ID,start_time,end_time,
   SUM(isstart) OVER(partition by id ORDER BY ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS DG 
FROM C1;
```

This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something with 3 parameters like the below:

```
select 
    id, start_time, end_time,
    case when @id = id and start_time >= @end_time then @reminder + 1 else 1 end as group_id,
    @id:=id as id_set,
    @reminder:= case when @id = id and start_time >= @end_time then @reminder + 1 else 1 end as reminder,
    @end_time:=end_time
from your_table t,
(select @id_check = 1) a,
(select @reminder = 1) b,
(select @end_time = '00:00:00') c
order by id, start_time;
```

1. `@end_time` to compare the end_time of the last row with the
   start_time of the current row
2. `@id` to compare the id of the last row with the id of
   the current row
3. `@reminder` to carry a count to the next row if the criteria based on the first two parameters are fulfilled and resets to 1 otherwise

the data I used:

```
create table your_table (id int(11), start_time time, end_time time);
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (102, '11:01:00', '11:30:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (101, '10:00:00', '10:20:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (100, '10:00:00', '12:00:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (100, '10:15:00', '12:30:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (100, '12:15:00', '12:45:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (100, '13:00:00', '14:00:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (101, '09:00:00', '13:00:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (101, '09:30:00', '13:30:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (105, '10:30:01', '11:00:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (105, '10:00:00', '10:20:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (105, '10:21:00', '10:30:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (105, '14:30:01', '15:00:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (106, '10:00:00', '10:22:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (107, '10:19:00', '10:20:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (108, '10:01:00', '10:16:00');
```

Comment: The group id column from the reminder is not changing. All the values get reset to 1

Comment: I'll add the test data I used for this to my post - works perfectly fine for me

Comment: @Nav fyi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669428/why-do-i-get-a-different-output-for-the-same-query