# Why do I get a different output for the same query?

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to answer this question: [Group rows if they have overlapping time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656420/group-rows-if-they-have-overlapping-time-intervals/59666764?noredirect=1#comment105496122_59666764)

I came up with a solution that works fine for me but but that I cant replicate on fidel. Now I wonder why this is.

data:

```
create table your_table (id int(11), start_time time, end_time time);
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (102, '11:01:00', '11:30:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (101, '10:00:00', '10:20:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (100, '10:00:00', '12:00:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (100, '10:15:00', '12:30:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (100, '12:15:00', '12:45:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (100, '13:00:00', '14:00:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (101, '09:00:00', '13:00:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (101, '09:30:00', '13:30:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (105, '10:30:01', '11:00:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (105, '10:00:00', '10:20:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (105, '10:21:00', '10:30:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (105, '14:30:01', '15:00:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (106, '10:00:00', '10:22:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (107, '10:19:00', '10:20:00');
insert into your_table (id, start_time, end_time) values (108, '10:01:00', '10:16:00');
```

Basically the question is how to create the column `group_id` as shown in below screenshot. Idea of `group_id` is to look at all the subgroups that share the same value for `id` and increase by 1 whenever there is no overlapping time between two rows - that is when start_time of `current row` > than `end_time` of last row

[image]

my query gives the above output and seems to work fine on my machine (MySQL workbench):

```
select 
    id, start_time, end_time,
    case when @id = id and start_time >= @end_time then @reminder + 1 else 1 end as group_id,
    @id:=id as id_set,
    @reminder:= case when @id = id and start_time >= @end_time then @reminder + 1 else 1 end as reminder,
    @end_time:=end_time
from your_table t,
(select @id_check = 1) a,
(select @reminder = 1) b,
(select @end_time = '00:00:00') c
order by id, start_time;
```

However on fidel I can't replicate it (all values are 1):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1d94a856d2aebfca1c1b37dc425131cf

Is this due to my workbench version?

Comment: MySQL does not guarantees in which order expressions are evaluated in the `select` clause. So you cannot guarantee whether assignment `@id:=id` is evaluated before or after the other expressions.

Comment: What is best practice for doing any kind of ranking within subgroups then?

Comment: Upgrade to MySQL 8.0 and use [RANK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank).

Comment: ok, I'll check that out. Thank you!